Next JS not taking multiple props for FontAwesome icon
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTableCells, faSharp, faRegular} />
I am trying to add faSharp, faRegular to the source about.
But unfortunately my application is screaming. I need them because they are defaults of the exact table cells with no border-radius added.
I tried what is above and does not work
